# How to avoid fragment to re display all content using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

When i switch between Fragment tabs, My Asynctask calls again because i have call my `dataRecieving()` method  in **onCreateView** . I know fragment life cycle of fragment,but how could i avoid fragment from recalling that method. How could i know fragment displays for the second time.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_all_promotion, container,false);

    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    dataRecieving();

    return view;
}
```

but how can i avoid re calling my dataRecieving method.

**What have i tried**

i have put dataRecieving method in onCreate, but nothing displayed.

Or **Is there any delegate/method with which i know that fragment displays for the second time.**

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable, and check it in your onCreateView method. In onDestroyView (when the fragment going from the screen), you can set this variable to false and then next time your onCreateView is called, you know, that it is showing for 2nd time.

```
public class FragmentRecipes extends Fragment{

   private boolean backstack = false;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_all_promotion, container,false);

    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    if(savedInstanceState == null && !backstack){
       // this will run only for first time, when the fragment is created
       dataRecieving();
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
   super.onDestroyView();

   backstack = true;
}
```